# Why does Apple use this guideline "A label is often unnecessary when placeholder text is present"

Tags: guidelines, human-interface-guideline, apple

In which context does Apple use this guideline, and why did they do so? I can only see the logic in the context of having an input field where you search. It just seems a bit odd since it has so many negative consequences, sure it reduces clutter and shortens the length of the form but I think that does not make up for the consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is the source](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/user-interaction/data-entry/#:%7E:text=A%20label%20is%20often%20unnecessary,For%20related%20guidance%2C%20see%20Labels.) for your quote.

You can split data entries into two kinds:

- Fill and forget
- Fill and persist

## Fill and Forget

[image: A Login form]

In this scenario:

- The user lands upon some data entry interface
- The form is empty
- Once filled by the user there is an action to progress to the next "stage"
- The data entered is not persisted - it only enables progressing to the next "stage"
- Once submitted, the user cannot return to data entry interface (meaning there is no "previous" options, or no cyclic paths returning to that data entry in the user journey).

Gatekeepers are good examples for this data entries type. Examples:

- Login forms
- Captcha forms
- 2FA forms

And also:

- Contact request form
- Newsletter signup form

In these sort of cases, you could replace a label with a placeholder:

- The form is empty to begin with
- The place holder denotes the purpose of each field
- Forms are generally short so either the nature of each field is in the user's memory (eg, username), or there is little need to edit previously entered values.
- Once submitted there is no way back, so no issue with no labels or placeholders (due to the filled form).

## Fill and Persist

[image: A form for address entry]

Unlike the previous kind, once filled data is persisted and users *can* return to these data entry interfaces for editing purposes.

Examples are "delivery address" in a checkout wizard.

Here, it makes sense to put label or users will not be able to infer the nature of each field. (Users can infer from the values, but this is error-prone).

Comment: I see thanks for the clarification. However, why do they emphasize and write "often" I can't find any good examples besides the one I gave.

Comment: I'm not sure. A proper cognitive and contextual analysis could lead to the use of placeholders even when not immediately obvious. But I'd argue that more often than not data entries can be re-visited so placeholders won't be an optimal solution.

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Comment: Just to add on, I believe that Apple’s guidelines on the preference of placeholder text over labels is to encourage designers to reduce the amount of user memory needed when designing forms in general. Forms should be simple to fill, convenient and effortless in exerting memory recall by users.